# Getting values from one column conditional on SPECIFIC values in another columns and putting those values in a new data frame

Tags: r

I want to create a new data frame which contains values form multiple column in another data frame. The follow is just a sample form a large data set.

i have tried the following:

```
for(i in 1:dim(df1)[1]){
      if (df1$order_type_1[i] == "ball"){
          df2$order_time_1[i] == df1$order_time_1[i]
         } else if (df1$order_type_1[i] != "ball" ){
         df2$order_time_2[i] == df1$order_time_1[i]
         } else if (df1$order_type_1[i] == "ball" & df1$order_type_2[i] != 
         NA){df2$order_time_2[i] == df1$order_time_2[i]}
```

}

This will create the data frame form where I want to extract time values.

```
df1 <- data.frame( ID = c(1:7), order_type_1 = c("ball", "ball", "pen", 
"pen", "watch", "cap", "hat"), order_type_2 = c(NA, "pen", "watch", 
"cap","hat", NA, NA), order_time_1 = c(1.0, 2.1, 3.2, 4.3, 5.4, 6.5, 7.6), 
order_time_2 = c(NA, 11.6, 12.7, 13.8, 14.9, 15.1, 16.2))
```

Expected Output looks like this:-

```
df2 <- data.frame( ID = c(1:7),order_time_1 = c(1.0, 2.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), 
order_time_2 = c(NA, 11.6, 3.2, 4.3, 5.4, 6.5, 7.6))
```

Comment: Instead of using a `for` loop with `if/else`, try with `ifelse`

Comment: Now, it should be fine

Comment: After, running the following code:    ifelse(df1$order_type_1 == "ball", df2$order_time_1 == df1$order_time_1, "0")  It gives NA (where value needs to be present) and "0" where NA/0 needs to be present.

Comment: It is a bit confusing.  YOu said the expected output as 'df2', then why you are using `df2`  to create `ifelse`

Comment: got it! thank you!   df2$order_time_1 <- ifelse(df1$order_type_1 == "ball", df1$order_time_1, 0)

Comment: I posted a solutoin below, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  transmute(ID, order_time_1 = replace(order_time_1, 
           order_type_1 != "ball", NA), order_time_2)
```

---

If we need a `for` loop

```
v1 <- numeric(nrow(df1))
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df1))) {
   v1[i] <- if(df1$order_type_1[i] == "ball") df1$order_time_1[i] else NA_real_
  }

transform(df1[c("ID", "order_type_1")], order_time_1 = v1)
```